# filter a product collection by attribute and tag

Tags: collection, ce-1.8.1.0, tags

How can I filter a collection by both an attribute and by a tag?

I can filter a product collection by doing:

```php
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( $storeId );

$collection = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' );

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection */
$collection = $product->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect( '*' );

$collection->addAttributeToFilter( 'attribute_set_id', $attribute_set_id );
```

And I can get the tag ID by doing:

```
$tag = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->loadByName($tag_name);
```

I've found that you can do like this to filter by tag:

```php
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect( '*' ) //
                    ->addTagFilter($tag->getId()) //filter by the tag object
                    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

But I'd like to combine the first type of filter with the second, as to be able to filter both by attribute and optionally by tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

$collection is your product collection.

```
$collection->joinTable(
            array('tag_relation' => 'tag/relation'), 'product_id = entity_id',
            array('tag_relation_id' => 'tag_relation_id', 'tag_id' => 'tag_id'), null, 'inner'
        );
        $collection->joinTable(
            array('tag' => 'tag/tag'), 'tag_id = tag_id', array('tag_name' => 'name'), null, 'inner'
        );
        $collection->getSelect()->where("tag.name {$operator} (?)", $tagString);
        $collection->getSelect()->where("tag.status = ?", Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_APPROVED);
```

In the code above $operator would be your usual SQL operators (<,>,=,!= etc) 
$tagString will be the value of the tag you are interested in linking.

I use this in my [Dynamic Category Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dynamic-category-products-automated-category-products-shop-by-brands-shop-by-any-attribute.html) extension to allow rules that bring in products based on tags.

Comment: Great. A pity magento ORM doesn't allow to do this directly, without having to write your own joins, but nice solution nonetheless.

Comment: You are the man!